# Set Theory. Levy's Basis Theorem

Tags: set-theory

This question is with respect to Thm 1.3, p. 195 of Smullyan and Fitting's Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis (2010 ed.). The set B obtained in the proof is said to be extensional. But The Tarski-Vaught Theorem used to obtain B says class K must be extensional for B to be extensional. But K is not assumed to be extensional with respect to relation R. Then the Mostowski-Sheperdson Theorem is applied to the relational system (B,R). But that requires (B,R) to be proper, well-founded and extensional with respect to R. I therefore believe the Thm. 1.3 requires additional hypotheses that the relational system (K,R) be proper, extensional and well-founded. These properties relate to R, not the relational system (K,<) where "< or =" is a well-ordering of K. I see nothing to suggest that K consist of constructible sets. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I think you're right about the point that $K$ must be extensional (or at least I don't immediately see a way to make it work without, and agree that's ostensibly required by the theorem cited). As for well-founded/proper, we're just considering the class as a relational system $(K,\in)$, so it automatically satisfies those properties... there's no $R$ here (other than the completely unrelated $\Sigma_1$ relation $R$).

Comment: The theorem is with respect to a relation R that is Σ on class K. The application of the Mostowski-Sheperdson map is with respect to R. The required properties of extension, proper and well founded must be with respect to the relational system (B,R). ε won’t do. R is here definitely related.

Comment: No, that's wrong. Does it say in the proof that we are applying the map "with respect to $R$" or to the relational system $(B,R)$? No, it just says apply it to $B.$ This means it is being applied to the relational system $(B,\in),$ as is generally the case when no (nonstandard) membership relation is specified. The use of the letter $R$ to denote the relation we're reflecting is just an unfortunate clash of notation. (Also if you look at and think about the statement of theorem 3.2 you will see they are implicitly using $\in$ as the relation... what else would "extensional subset" mean?)

Comment: Thank you. All that’s needed is to additionally state in the hypotheses that K extensional. I note that (K,∈) is not automatically extensional unless K is transitive. In the proof R serves to provide the formula φ. Then only R is needed in applications without writing out an explicit formula. Since B is a set (B ∈,) is proper. I don’t recall seeing anywhere in the text an explicit statement adopting that every set in V is well founded. But it does appear to be osmotically implied at P. 99, “[A]s time went on, assuming all sets were well founded became the standard.” Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. By the way, this book is a complete mess and I would suggest using a different one… e.g. it’s not too much to ask for firm commitment on whether we’re assuming the axiom of foundation. Another (more innocuous) annoyance is the terminology: this is a well-known theorem of Levy, but I’ve literally never heard it called “Levy’s basis theorem” and nothing comes up on Google when I search that, so I feel it’s not merely my ignorance. Same goes with “Godel’s isomorphism theorem”, which to make it worse, has a real name people use (the condensation lemma).

Comment: Can you provide a reference to another book you'd recommend.  I have found S&F sometime problematic beyond the many typos in it. I've almost finished it, so I will complete it. But another more current book that addresses forcing would be welcome.

Comment: Kunen is the go-to for forcing. I actually started with S+F and then did Kunen (1980). Kunen also did a more recent book on the same topic. Could also try Halbeisen's book or Weaver's "forcing for mathematicians".

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look at these to see what's readily available.